# concatenate the output values in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create table item_value_tab
as
select 1110 Item_value,000394 bb_to_no, 55555 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000394 bb_to_no, 66666 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000394 bb_to_no, 77777 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000123 bb_to_no, 1111 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000124 bb_to_no, 2222 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000124 bb_to_no, 3333 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000011 bb_to_no, 75257 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual
union all
select 1110 Item_value,000011 bb_to_no, 65257 order_number, 'ABC' cust_no from dual;
```

Take below code in Cursor 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT DECODE(nvl(Item_value,0),bb_to_no,null,'Item  Value '||nvl(bb_to_no,0)||' Is not correct for order number '||order_number||' FOR Customer  '||cust_no) vmsg
from item_value_tab;
```

Getting Output

```
Item Value 000394 Is not correct for order number 55555 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000394 Is not correct for order number 66666 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000394 Is not correct for order number 77777 FOR Customer  ABC

Item Value 000123 Is not correct for order number 1111 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000124 Is not correct for order number 2222 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000124 Is not correct for order number 3333 FOR Customer  ABC

Item Value 000011 Is not correct for order number 75257 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000011 Is not correct for order number 65257 FOR Customer  ABC
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create table item_not_tab
as
select 0 item_id,53555 bb_to_no,1052 order_number,'AAA' cust_no from dual
union all
select 0 item_id,53655 bb_to_no,1138 order_number,'AAA' cust_no from dual;

Need to take the below code in cursor 2
select DECODE(nvl(item_id,0),0,'items not created for  '||bb_to_no||'order number '||order_number||' FOR Customer  '||cust_no,NULL) vmsg
from item_not_tab;
```

Getting Output

```
items not created for 53555 order number 1052 FOR Customer  AAA
items not created for 53655 order number 1052 FOR Customer  AAA
```

Expected output

```
Item Value Problems
Item Value 000394 Is not correct for order number 55555,66666,77777 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000123,000124 Is not correct for order number 1111 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000124 Is not correct for order number 2222,3333 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000011 Is not correct for order number 75257,65257 FOR Customer  ABC

Items not found Problems
items not created for 53555,53655 order number 1052 FOR Customer  AAA
```

note: please don't joins both tables in one cursor, I need to take 2 cursors. Both tables are same actually, but test case purpose I have as 2 d/f tables

oracle 11g 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: Post the `PL/SQL` code where you generate the **LOOP**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first **concatenate** the `tot_number` inside the **LOOP**, and then use the value **outside the LOOP**.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v VARCHAR2(100);
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT 55555 str FROM dual
  6    UNION
  7    SELECT 66666 str FROM dual
  8    UNION
  9    SELECT 77777 str FROM dual
 10    )
 11    LOOP
 12      v:= ltrim(v||','||i.str, ',');
 13    END LOOP;
 14    dbms_output.put_line('Output is concatenated '||v);
 15  END;
 16  /
Output is concatenated 55555,66666,77777

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you lalit, i need to show same like this BB Value 000394 Is not correct for tot number 55555,66666 ,7777 FOR Customer  ABC

Comment: if i use your code the then i will get  BB Value 000394 Is not correct for tot number 55555,66666 ,7777,88888 FOR Customer ABC , for another rows

Comment: Then you need to put an `IF` condition before the concatenation in the loop, store the previous `BB_Value` value in a variable, and check the current value is same or not. it is pretty simple. Post some input data and desired output if you need more help.

Comment: please check the code, i don't know how format the code here please don't mind

Comment: Don't add additional information as an answer, you should edit your question and add it there.

Comment: check the edited code and thank you for your helping..:)

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the below QUERY :

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.bb_to_no, 
 (SELECT listagg(order_number,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1 desc) 
  FROM item_value_tab i WHERE o.bb_to_no = i.bb_to_no) AS total_num,
 (SELECT DISTINCT(k.cust_no) FROM item_value_tab k 
   WHERE o.bb_to_no = k.bb_to_no) AS cust_name
 FROM item_value_tab o
```

(OR)

EDIT : Please check this.

```
//It create collection of type table to store all the order_numbers

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

// Below procedure will concatenate the list of order_numbers stored in
// the above created collection type.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string
(p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
 p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN
     FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
      IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
       l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
     END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
   END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
 END tab_to_string;


 SELECT bb_to_no,cust_no,
   tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(order_number) AS t_varchar2_tab)) 
  AS tot_number
 FROM item_value_tab
 GROUP BY bb_to_no,cust_no;
```

P.S : you can find more information on COLLECT() function on below link.

```
  http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306
```

Comment: Thank you Yathish, please don't use in select statement i need to use separate select (plsql code) and don't use joins on both tables both are same , i need to get different output messages

Comment: Did you exceute my SQL query and checked the output ?? If you execute the above SQL statement. It gives you list as u expected, you can take it in cursor and can print it in your way.

Comment: Yes i did but getting ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long at listagg table

Comment: hmm!! The reason it is showing that error is that the listagg function is trying to concatenate a the values which may be greater than 4000 characters.

Comment: Yes...how to resolve this error ,or any another solution on this

Comment: I have EDITed my post. Please check that it.

Comment: I have added one more solution it, Please check my answer with EDIT.

Comment: Nice Query thank you  how to get only one if the see table item_not_tab data out put please

Comment: what ?? did you try executing those TYPE, FUNCTION and QUERY.

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
 
 I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: working fine in 11.1.1.0 version but not in  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
 
 I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
  Showing error at COLLECT

Comment: I have totally 550 order_number concatenated,it contains 6 length , so please suggest me how to do this

Comment: can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: Please check the above solution in EDIT, it should work.

Comment: Hi, getting ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

Comment: Hi i used inner for loop's , in the 2nd loop concatenated , but this not working  Item Value 000394 Is not correct for order number 55555 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000494 Is not correct for order number 55555 FOR Customer  ABC
Item Value 000594 Is not correct for order number 55555 FOR Customer  ABC